# What is an extreme term for Feature creep, Software bloat and Code bloat?

Tags: terminology, programmer-relations

**I am looking for a term or principle** that describes software or a website that has many:

- "Features" that are not really features that no end users want or will ever use.
- "Features" that are so poorly implemented that no end users are able to use.
- "Features" that have never been successfully implemented before elsewhere.

**All of the "features" create a lot of unnecessary testing and bugs with no reward.**

---

**Research:** I have read through other sites and on Wikipedia: [Feature Creep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_creep) , [Software Bloat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_bloat) and [Code Bloat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_bloat). They are not quite right in that some or a few users are actually happy that the features are present. They might cost a lot of coding time, have a performance cost for the other 99% of users and clutter the UI but some users do want the features.

---

**Use Case:** "The new website is full of Non-Features," or "the App suffers from Principle XYZ."

Answer (score 1):

"Quality is value to someone (who matters)", Jerry Weinberg.

The three points talk about not delivering value to some of the people who matter.
Thus you can say the application is of low quality to those people.

Answer (score 1):

**The use case you defined is "Absence of error, fallacy"**

Meaning the software product has no bugs , it has no errors but the feature it self is not what user want . It creates an illusion of stable product but actually is just "fallacy"

> fallacy:
>
> a failure in reasoning which renders an argument invalid.

**So in your case you can use below terms when explaining the issue:**

The product has issue of "absence of error" fallacy due to feature creeps that are in no way aligned to customer requirement.

There is huge design and requirement gathering flaw in the product and project level , both in usability and functionality level.

**To add to the research on terms**

Its good to have specific terms that can define a problem in hand , but going too much technical about a problem might hinder the chances of getting a valid brainstorming session as half of the room won't be aware of the terms you use.

so try to keep it simple "Language" than filling it with fancy terms if you are looking for really interaction with the target audience. Or also explain meaning of terms as you use them, so that the session becomes a interesting learning session alson.